# OSGi: choices for Android development

Tags: android, osgi

I have an OSGi project I would like to port it to Android, what are my choices beyond Apache Felix? and what are their advantages? has a clear consensus arisen toward a certain system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prosyst](http://prosyst.com) have an OSGi framework for Android, but it's not free (however it does include loads of extras for Javascript, accessing phone's services, etc).

Otherwise I think you're pretty much on your own, but as the framework API has been standardised you could (easy) write your own basic runner, [embedding](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) Felix/Equinox/etc and even allowing the user to decide on the framework to use as part of launch (or using the SPI standard and picking up the [FrameworkFactory](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/launch/FrameworkFactory.html))

Answer (score 0):

Another option that has recently been developed is to use PojoSR. Although it is not a full OSGi framework, you get all the benefits of using the service registry, without the module layer. Largely depending on what you're actually aiming for when using OSGi in Android, this might be an option.